# D&D-style compound dice expression regex

Tags: java, regex, dice

I'm working on a project in Java that involves a user entering a dice expression. I'm using a regex to validate the input to ensure it's a valid D&D style dice expression. What I mean by that is that expressions like these:

```
d20
2D12+ 4 - 2
12d4-2d6+7 + d8
7 + 1d12
```

Would all be valid. Whereas expressions like these:

```
-2d6+4
-d8 - 5
12
2d0 + 5
1d6 + 0d2 - 1
0d6
```

Would all be invalid.
So far, the closest regex I've managed to make is:

```
^((((0+\d+|[1-9]\d*|)(d|D)(0+\d+|[1-9]\d*))|(\d+))((\ *(\+|\-)\ *)(?=(((0+\d+|[1-9]\d*|)(d|D)(0+\d+|[1-9]\d*))|(\d+))))?)+$
```

However, this regex still matches expressions like "0d6". Any assistance in creating a regex for this would be much appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't sound or look to me like regex is the way to go here. Write a small bundle of dice and associated parsing classes and you'll have a much easier time understanding your code when you come back to it to maintain or expand it.

Comment: Try [`^(?!\d+$)(?:[1-9]\d*)?[dD]?[1-9]\d*(?:\s*[-+\/*]\s*(?:[1-9]\d*)?[dD]?[1-9]\d*)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/5YkjuF/1).

Comment: Agree with @daniu - this sounds like a case for a [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), not a regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^(?!\d+$)(([1-9]\d*)?[Dd]?[1-9]\d*( ?[+-] ?)?)+(?<![+-] ?)$`

Explanation:

```
^              | Enforce beginning of string
(?!\\d+$)      | If 1+ digits at end of string are matched, don't match the following:
(              | Begin group
  ([1-9]\\d*)? |   Optionally match numbers not starting with 0 of any length
  [Dd]?        |   Optionally match either "D" or "d"
  [1-9]\\d*    |   Match numbers not starting with 0 of any length
  ( ?[+-] ?)?  |   Optionally match a "+" or "-" optionally surrounded by spaces
)+             | End group; one or more of these should exist
(?<![+-] ?)    | A "+" or "-" with an optional space shouldn't precede the end
$              | Enforce end of string
```

#### [Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/98N5pp/3)

Example code:

```
String userInput = "12d4-2d6+7 + d8";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?!\\d+$)(([1-9]\\d*)?[Dd]?[1-9]\\d*( ?[+-] ?)?)+$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(userInput);
boolean b = m.matches();

System.out.println(b); // true
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! The detailed explanation is especially helpful. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Surram Take note that this regex incorrectly matches "7d+".

Comment: @daniu I'm not sure how you're getting that. I tested that value and it doesn't match.

Comment: @Adam You're right, sorry, I mistyped. The erronous match is for "7d4+".

Comment: Updated the regex to fix the problem.